# Suppress slf4j debug messages

Tags: slf4j, suppress

I have a package imported through Maven which logs *a lot* of `DEBUG` level messages. Since I can't control this package's `logback.xml` (?), can I in some other fashion suppress the package's output to `stdout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I can't control this package's `logback.xml` (?)

Yes you can:

```
<logger name="com.example.foo" level="ERROR" />
```

where `com.example.foo` is the package you want to filter. It is typically consistent with artifact's `groupId`. Also consider `WARN` level, `OFF` is also possible, however it may hide important problems.